# OpenXML replacing XmlNode value leaves residual data

Tags: c#, xml, openxml

When using the code below I get corrupted xlsx file which can be fixed by removing the residual data from the `connections.xml` file.
What is causing the issue and how to fix this?

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument excelDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file.FullName, true))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookpart = excelDoc.WorkbookPart;
    ConnectionsPart connPart = workbookpart.ConnectionsPart;

    string spreadsheetmlNamespace = @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";
    NameTable nt = new NameTable();
    XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
    nsManager.AddNamespace("sh", spreadsheetmlNamespace);

    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
    xdoc.Load(connPart.GetStream());
    XmlNode oxmlNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/sh:connections/sh:connection/sh:dbPr/@connection", nsManager);

    oxmlNode.Value = oxmlNode.Value.Replace(oxmlNode.Value, "foo");
    xdoc.Save(connPart.GetStream());
}
```

What comes out as `connections.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<connections xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <connection id="1" keepAlive="1" name="LCR" type="5" refreshedVersion="4" background="1" saveData="1">
    <dbPr connection="foo" command="test" commandType="1" />
    <olapPr sendLocale="1" rowDrillCount="1000" serverFill="0" serverFont="0" serverFontColor="0" />
  </connection>
</connections>y Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Disable Prefetch Facts=True" command="test" commandType="1"/><olapPr sendLocale="1" rowDrillCount="1000" serverFill="0" serverFont="0" serverFontColor="0"/></connection></connections>
```

Please note the residual data at the end. If this is removed, xlsx can be open again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding extra line which clears the part before adding data to it.

```
...
oxmlNode.Value = oxmlNode.Value.Replace(oxmlNode.Value, newConnection);
connPart.FeedData(connPart.GetStream()); //Added
xdoc.Save(connPart.GetStream())
...
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpart.feeddata(v=office.14).aspx):

> Feed data into the part stream. The stream of the part will be
>   **truncated** at first.

Found the answer thanks to SO Related question section. Particularly, [OpenXML replace specific customxml part of word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636258/openxml-replace-specific-customxml-part-of-word-document?rq=1).